# How can I get text to stand up straight?

Tags: modeling, 3d-cursor

I'm working on an AR project that includes 3D text. The text is done and extruded but I'm having trouble getting the text to stand up straight.

I have a two button mouse and I can operate the rotate, scale, etc. I know I'm doing something wrong and I'm guessing the answer is fairly simple yet, I need help.

Comment: Are you trying to figure out how to rotate it so it's standing straight up?

Comment: Yes. Thats exactly what I want it to. I want it to stand up straight. Do I need a three button mouse?

Comment: no.  just press r on the keyboard and type in the number of degrees it needs to be rotated by in order to stand on end (probably 90 degrees).  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks so much. I really appreciate your advice.